# How do I bind a command to a key press in an Avalonia MVVM app built with the Community Toolkit?

Tags: mvvm, keyboard, windows-community-toolkit, avalonia

I am developing a simple desktop MVVM application with Avalonia and the Community Toolkit (the most recent stable versions to the date - Avalonia 11.00.2 and Community Toolkit 8.2.1).

I want it to be keyboard-controlled, having no button controls on the form.

How do I bind a command (a viewmodel method attributed with the Community Toolkit `RelayCommandAttribute`) to a key press, e.g. <kbd>F3</kbd>?

In fact I am interested in both cases: when the view is a Window (the `IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime` case) and when it is a UserControl (the `ISingleViewApplicationLifetime` case) but any single one of these would already be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that the way I was trying to do this was correct, I just misspelled my command name.

Adding the following to the `MainWindow.axaml` does the job binding `MyCommand` to the <kbd>F3</kbd> button:

```
<Window.KeyBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="F3" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
</Window.KeyBindings>
```

This works even though the actual command is defined in a viewmodel of `MainView` which is a control within the main window (as well as when it is defined in a viewmodel of the window itself i.e. in both cases I have mentioned in the question).

Comment: We could have answered this too, if you had posted your code with the question.  Ok, we had voted to close, because this was caused by a typo.

Comment: @SirRufo I believe this can be useful to others as this seems to be lacking from the manual anyway.